# Clarification on the particle following 今年

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-は

In an assignment I wrote「今年にローラースケートを習いたいです。」 which was corrected to 「今年はローラースケートを習いたいです。」My guess is that it was corrected because in this sentence, "this year" is the ~topic~. Is that correct?

and in order for「今年にローラースケートを習いたいです。」to be correct, I should have added 「私は」 making 「今年に私はローラースケートを習いたいです。」

Answer (score 8):

今年 doesn't take any particle when it is not topicalized and it works as a simple adverb. 今日, 昨日, 明日 and so on doesn't take に, either. If you want to topicalize 私, you should say:

> 私は今年ローラースケートを習いたいです。

But ensure topicalizing 私 is natural in your context.